# Convert array of strings to array of floats in Ruby to get mean/average value

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, math

I have a `file.txt` with a float value on each line:

```
23.45
12.01
15
900.6543
```

I want to get the mean/average of these values, so I read them text. Here's my `script.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'
array = IO.readlines 'file.txt'
array.map(&:to_f)
numerator = array.reduce(0) { |a, v| a + v }
denominator = array.count
mean = numerator.to_f / denominator.to_f
puts mean
```

I get the following error with `ruby script.rb`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from list2.rb:7:in `<main>'
        3: from list2.rb:7:in `reduce'
        2: from list2.rb:7:in `each'
        1: from list2.rb:7:in `block in <main>'
list2.rb:7:in `+': String can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you used `array.map(&:to_f)` you created a new array of floats... that you did nothing with. You either want to assign that to a variable and use it, or use `#map!` to modify `array`.

```
array.map!(&:to_f)
```

Comment: The important thing is that you understand why it worked. :-)

Comment: Irrelevant to your question, but you can streamline `array.reduce(0) { |a, v| a + v }` to `array.reduce(0, &:+)` or even just `array.reduce(&:+)`.

Comment: great tip, even shorter script!

Comment: `p mean = (array.sum(&:to_r) / array.size).to_f` and you don't need bigdecimal.